# Extra count query is running for every normal query in Rails 3. How to fix this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My model is below, when I call this two sql queries are executing one count + original

```
 class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base


    class << self
      def find_alternatives()
         Drug.where("gpi like '3760%'").select('gpi, drugs.prod_desc_abbrev').group(:gpi)
      end
    end
  end
```

In my console I find two queries executing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, gpi AS gpi FROM `drugs` WHERE (gpi like '3760%') GROUP BY gpi

SELECT gpi, drugs.prod_desc_abbrev FROM `drugs` WHERE (gpi like '3760%') GROUP BY gpi
```

My controller

```
 def drug_alternatives
    @alternative_drugs = Drug.find_alternatives(params[:gpi])
 end
```

My Views

```
 <% @alternative_drugs.each_with_index do |result, count| %>

<%= result.gpi %>
    <%= result.prod_desc_abbrev %>

 <% end %>
```

How can this be fixed. Why is two queries getting executed?

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: could you try `@alternative_drugs = Drug.find_alternatives(params[:gpi]).all` in your controller, and see if it helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggested by – [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert)

in your controller try

```
@alternative_drugs = Drug.find_alternatives(params[:gpi]).all
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, in your view you are using `@alternative_drugs.count` when you should use `@alternative_drugs.size`.